# PHP echo file size located in pc

Tags: php

Ι have somewhere located in my pc a txt file, let's say for example `C:\Users\my_file.txt`. Is there a way to print its size? As I search it, I am given:

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
echo $filename . ': ' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes';
```

But what path should I give to filename variable?

Comment: the file should be located under your server. and give the file path to the $filname variable.

Comment: Question contains the answer: `C:\Users\my_file.txt`

Comment: Use filesize('C:\Users\my_file.txt')

Comment: If you want the size of `C:\Users\my_file.txt`, then why did you write `$filename = 'somefile.txt';`?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, the path separator is `/`. In Windows, it is either `\`,  `/` or `\\`.
I personally use front-slashes `/` on both OS so I never get confused.

---

Below you can find 3 valid `full paths` on Windows, i.e.:

```
C:/Users/my_file.txt
```

or

```
C:\\Users\\my_file.txt
```

or simply:

```
C:\Users\my_file.txt
```

---

To get the `filesize` you can use the function [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)

```
$myFile = "C:\Users\my_file.txt"
echo filesize($myFile) . "bytes";
```

---

If the file is on the **same dir** as the php script you can use a `relative path`:

```
$myFile = "my_file.txt"
echo filesize($myFile) . "bytes";
```

---

If the file is **one dir below** you can also use a `relative path`.

```
$myFile = "../my_file.txt"
echo filesize($myFile) . "bytes";
```

---

Another `relative path` example, this time 1 dir UP:

```
$myFile = "./newdir/my_file.txt"
echo filesize($myFile) . "bytes";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you just give filesize an absolute path.
If that is not an option, you have to give it a relative path (relative to the PHP-file you are in).

Say you have a dir `files` with another folder in it (`php`), and in it again there is a file called `filesize.php`. In the `files` folder you have a file called `bigfile.txt`.
To get the filesize of the `bigfile.txt` in your php script which is in `php/filesize.php` you could do one of the following:

```
<?php
$filesize = filesize("../bigfile.txt"); // One folder up (relative)
$filesize = filesize("C:\files\bigfile.txt"); // Absolute path
```